# How to retrieve the most present pair in groups of three columns, with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I am working on ice hockey software: trying to find out who in your team has collected the most points with a specific player (in this example `user_id = 1`).

Data structure:

```
goal_user_id | assist_user_id | second_assist_user_id
-----------------------------------
1            | 13856          | null
1            | 15157          | null
1            | 15157          | null
1            | 15157          | 18733
345          | 1              | 28703
18733        | 1              | null
36014        | 34867          | 1
```

Desired output:

```
user_id | partner_id | total_points
-----------------------------------
1       | 15157      | 3
1       | 18733      | 2
1       | 13856      | 1
1       | 345        | 1
1       | 28703      | 1
1       | 34867      | 1
1       | 36014      | 1
```

SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1587/4/0 (Note: SQLFiddle has been acting weird today).

I managed to get it done on the across two columns but couldn't figure out for three:

```
SELECT 

  COUNT(goal_user_id) as total_points, 

  CASE WHEN goal_user_id <> 1 
    THEN goal_user_id
    ELSE assist_one_user_id
  END as partner_id,

  CASE WHEN goal_user_id < assist_one_user_id
    THEN CONCAT(goal_user_id,'-',assist_one_user_id) 
    ELSE CONCAT(assist_one_user_id,'-',goal_user_id) 
  END as player_pair 

FROM goals 

WHERE 
  assist_one_user_id IS NOT NULL AND (goals.goal_user_id = 1 OR goals.assist_one_user_id = 1)

GROUP BY player_pair

ORDER BY total_points DESC
```

Comment: @Strawberry No. Only managed to count across the first two columns instead of three.

Comment: I've seen SQL Fiddle fail a few times this year - think it is under too much load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My inclination is to break all the rows out into pairs of users.  Then do the aggregation based on that:

```
select u2, count(*) as total_points
from ((select goal_user_id as u1, assist_one_user_id as u2 from goals) union all
      (select assist_one_user_id, goal_user_id from goals) union all
      (select goal_user_id, assist_two_user_id from goals) union all
      (select assist_two_user_id, goal_user_id from goals) union all
      (select assist_one_user_id, assist_two_user_id from goals) union all
      (select assist_two_user_id, assist_one_user_id from goals)
     ) uu
where uu.u1 = 1 and uu.u2 is not null
group by u2
order by total_points desc;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1587/20) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Works great! FYI it took 2+ seconds to run on 80 000 goals but added a where clause on season_id and it's now 40ms. THANKS.